# How to annotate function that returns its argument

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I'm trying to write decorator that takes additionalparameter like this

```
def dec(arg):
    def modifier(cls) -> cls:
        # modify cls
        return cls;
    pass
    return modifier
pass
@dec(63)
class X:
    a: int = 47;
pass
```

This is, of course, error, since `cls` is not defined.
I've tried `dec(arg: int) -> Callable[[type], type]` and `modifier(cls: type) -> type`
but that messes up IntelliSense (vscode) (writing `X.` no longer offers `a`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to define a generic type that you can use to annotate your function. Use [Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) to annotate that the function accepts and returns types/classes of the TypeVar

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')


def dec(arg):
    def modifier(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
        # modify cls
        return cls
    return modifier


@dec(63)
class X:
    a: int = 47
```

Comment: I updated the question to the actual problem. The thing before actually worked

Comment: @Superior the same pattern should work for your nested decorator too